# How to use SharePoint list data in an Android application?

Tags: rest

We want to pull in the SharePoint list data into an Android application.

Is REST webservices the way ahead? Or is there any other method? Please provide articles reference in your answer.

How do we authenticate a request if using rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write a middle-ware service that uses Client Object Model to connect to SharePoint, I guess it will be more flexible.. Make calls to this middle-ware service from Android application..

You can authenticate using a particular user like:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://siteUrl"))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

    // Do your stuff
}
```

You can learn about Client Object Model here:

[Basic Operations in Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: What about using sharepoint web services like listdata.svc?

Comment: You can try using that, but I have heard there are some limitations on that.. If you go for custom web service, you will have more flexibility.. However what Rob has recommended is worth a try, I didn't know of that..

Comment: If I go to list out the methods to achieve this: 1. REST, 2. JSOM and 3. Robs method. Is there any other technique

Comment: Mine is the fourth one actually, 4. CSOM

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft announced a preview version of an SDK for Andriod at this year's SharePoint conference.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Android

You could also check out this session which shows how to authenticate with SharePoint from a non-Microsoft platform.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2012/SPC118